# How to merge Multiple arrays into single array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i query the address column from the database and i pass that multiple address to the Google Geocoder API and i store that latitude and longitude result in the `$coordinate` variable. When i `var_export($coordinate);` i get the output in the below format:

```
'[19.0759837,72.8776559]''[47.6062095,-122.3320708]''[12.9715987,77.5945627]'
```

but in when use `print_r(array($variablename));` i get the output in this format:

```
Array
(
 [0] => [19.0759837,72.8776559]
)
Array
(
  [0] => [47.6062095,-122.3320708]
)
Array
(
  [0] => [12.9715987,77.5945627]
)
```

But i want the output to be in single array something like this.

```
Array
(
 [0] => [19.0759837,72.8776559],
 [1] => [47.6062095,-122.3320708],
 [2] => [12.9715987,77.5945627]
)
```

This is php code:

```
<?php 
    // database connection code and query to fetch address column the database and pass address to geocode()
header("content-type: application/json");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini');
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $ordertracker = mysqli_query($connect, "select address from ordertracker");

                if (!$ordertracker)
                {
                    echo "Error fetching results: " . mysqli_error();

                }

        $address=array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ordertracker)) {
             $address= $row['address'];
              geocode($address);  
        }
    function geocode($address)
     {
                $address = urlencode($address);
                $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
                $geocode=file_get_contents($url);
                $output= json_decode($geocode);
                $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                $coordinate = "[" . $lat . "," . $long . "]";  
                var_export($coordinate);  
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Does `$coordinate` hold **one** coordinate or **all three** of them at once? If one, how do you fetch the next one? In a loop?

Comment: $coordinate variable holds all three of them add it will grow dynamically .

Comment: `print_r(array(your_string));` gives `Array
(
    [0] => [19.0759837,72.8776559][47.6062095,-122.3320708][12.9715987,77.5945627]
)`

Comment: @Gauravkb So then, is it a string? Could you please rewrite the examples in your question using `var_export` rather than `echo` and `print_r`?

Comment: @Siguza when i use var_export($coordinate); i get the output like this :
`'[19.0759837,72.8776559]''[47.6062095,-122.3320708]''[12.9715987,77.5945627]'`

Comment: Then your variable does **not** contain more than one of them at any given point (if you think otherwise, try `die($coordinate);`, that should convince you). You can simply have an array somewhere (outside of any loop you might have) and do `$arr[] = $coordinate;`.

Comment: Amendment: Looks like your `geocode()` function gets called three times in a row.

Comment: @Siguza i have added my php code as well, could you please help me to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array, then you should not use string literals and concatenation to build it, as that will result in a string.

Instead let your function result an array with two values (latitude and longitude) and append those pairs to your main array in your main loop:

```
$address = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ordertracker)) {
    $address[] = geocode($row['address']);
}
print_r($address);

function geocode($address) {
    $address = urlencode($address);
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
    $geocode = file_get_contents($url);
    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $coordinate = [$lat, $long];  
    return $coordinate;
}
```